# How to test Remove method without first adding elements

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a class with two methods, `Add(obj)` and `Remove(obj)`.

How do I unit test the `Remove` method when, initially, the private collection that holds the added properties is private?

I've read that it is bad practice to access private fields for unit tests. If I first use the `Add` method to fill the collection, the test will not be a unit test because it can fail when the `Add` method doesn't work.

```cs
class A
{
    private readonly ICollection<object> objs = new List<object>();

    public IReadOnlyCollection<object> Objs => this.objs.ToList();

    public void Add(object obj)
    {
        this.objs.Add(obj);
    }

    public void Remove(object obj)
    {
        this.objs.Remove(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: `....collection the test will not be a unit test because it can fail when the add method doesn't work.` I do not see a problem. This is a common scenario that state has to be created using functionality other than the functionality under test. If you have 2 failed unit tests that both fail on Add even though Remove is under test in one of them that is OK IMO.

Comment: You may use the return value of `objs.Remove(obj)` to figure if it could actually remove the specific object.

Answer (score 0):

It is still a unit test as your unit is `A`.

It is totally ok to do some setup.

Sometimes more than one test fails. In your case the Remove test fails if Add does not work.

```
// It is possible to add item to A.
// Arrange.
var sut = new A();
// Act.
sut.Add("a");
// Assert.
sut.Objs.Single().Should().Be("a", Reason: "Item is added.");
```

```
// It is possible to remove item from A.
// Arrange.
var sut = new A();
sut.Add("a");
sut.Objs.Single().Should().Be("a", Reason:"Sanity check");
// Act.
sut.Remove("a");
// Assert.
sut.Objs.IsEmpty(Reson: "Item is removed.");
```